# I am trying to change the policy in RASA from max_history: 5 to FullDialogueTrackerFeaturizer

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am new to using RASA and I was able to follow this guide:

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/

to set up RASA on Ubunto 18.04 on windows. I am now following a second guide:

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/rasa-tutorial/

and am at step 3, running the code in step 3 on Ubuntu cane back with the following result:

```
# Configuration for Rasa NLU.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: en
pipeline:
  - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
  - name: RegexFeaturizer
  - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    analyzer: "char_wb"
    min_ngram: 1
    max_ngram: 4
  - name: DIETClassifier
    epochs: 100
  - name: EntitySynonymMapper
  - name: ResponseSelector
    epochs: 100

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
  - name: TEDPolicy
    max_history: 5
    epochs: 100
  - name: MappingPolicy
```

Near the bottom, where it lists `max_history: 5` I would like to change the policy to `FullDialogueTrackerFeaturizer` so that the entire dialog is considered for the bots production. I have tried reading this article:

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/core-featurization/#featurization-conversations

although the article explains the function of the policy, I could not how to switch the policy.

My question is, how do I change the policy from max_history: 5 to FullDialogueTrackerFeaturizer?

Answer (score 1):

`FullDialogueTrackerFeaturizer` is not a **policy** it's a **featurizer**. What you're describing is infinite `max_history`. This is not a good idea, as your model will become enormous and very slow. Instead, set `max_history` high enough to account for any patterns in your training data. If you need to save data for use at an arbitrary point in a conversation, set a slot instead.